# simple Xcode Hello World displays controls then they immediately disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, macos

I haven't done any iOS development for like a year.
I updated OS to OS X 10.11.5 on my MacBook Pro.
I updated Xcode to v7.3
I did Xcode > New project, single view.
I set target OS to v7.1 because I'm testing on an iPhone4.
I used Storyboard to drag a Label onto the screen and set to Hello World.
But when I run simulator iPhone4S, it displays label then it disappears.
When I run on actual iPhone4, it displays nothing (all white).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that you didn't mistakenly drag the label onto your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` instead of your required storyboard. That would explain the vanishing part. Other than that you should probably use Auto-Layout for new projects. A convenient way to do a quick base layout is to select the UILabel and then go to the Editor menu and at the very bottom where it says "Resolve Auto-Layout Issues" select the entry Reset to Suggested Constraints..." in the lower section. Finally you may want to test on a different simulator - maybe for the iPad 2 just to check that your elements are there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add programmatically -

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 300, 50)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.numberOfLines = 0; 
    label.text = @"Hello World";
    [self.view addSubview:label];
```

if it is showing ,, then you have mistake in to adding the storyboard.
May be it helps you or feel free.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and what I did to fix this issue was clicking on the view and on the right pane, on the ¨Interface builder document¨, I changed the Opens in and that solved the problem.